# Storing the object of Select_list

Tags: ruby, watir

Please consider the below code

```
a=b.select_lists[0]
a.select("Agent")
```

In the aforementioned code, the first line is taking so much time, So Can anyone tell me Is there any way to store value of "a" object for further use without getting from b.select_lists[0]? Or Is there anyway can we directly get the value of 'a'?

The code which I am trying to write for the select list follows below

```
<select class="ng-valid ng-dirty" style="" ng-change="selectionsAgentType(AgentType)" ng-model="AgentType"> <select class="ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-change="AgentCategorySelected(agentoptions)" ng-model="agentoptions">
```

Comment: First, add html, please

Comment: Why html is needed for this? it's a normal select list. A page consist of many select list and I am choosing the first select_list using index 0 and I would like to store this a. That's what my question

Comment: Given that the problem is performance related, it would help to give the HTML so that we can reproduce your problem. Without being able to reproduce the problem, we would be blindly guessing on what you could do.

Comment: I would give you the two select list code below, <select class="ng-valid ng-dirty" style="" ng-change="selectionsAgentType(AgentType)" ng-model="AgentType"> <select class="ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-change="AgentCategorySelected(agentoptions)" ng-model="agentoptions"> Is there any way could I access this select list?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of ways to access that select list. However, without the entire page, it is extremely difficult to suggest one that will have good performance.

Comment: I know many ways are there,but many of them reduces the speed, for an instance b.select_lists[0].select("hi") or b.select_list(:index,0).select("hi") or b.select_list(:xpath=>'.//*[@ng-model="AgentType"]').select("hi") but all are reduces the speed of selection, the last one i have given takes 23 sec to for selection. that's what I asked is there anything is possible using ng-model?

Answer (score 1):

If `option` with `text: 'Agent'` is unique on this page.

If you need just simulate `select`

```
b.option(:text, 'Agent').select
```

Also, if you need `value` of this `option`

```
a = b.option(:text, 'Agent').value
```

Else,

```
b.select_lists.first.option(:text, 'Agent').select


a =  b.select_lists.first.option(:text, 'Agent').value
```

Comment: hi,Thanks,I know the idea you have stated here, if I use 'first' function then it's faster, but I can't use the first function while I try to second element, then I need to go for select_lists[1],If I use this index to locate the select list, then it's very slower. My select_list code follows, If you could provide me any other way to point out this select list, that would be helpful for me

"<select class="ng-valid" style="" ng-change="AgentCategory(agentoptions)" ng-model="agent">"

Comment: @RAJ There are all `select_lists` have `class="ng-valid"` ?

Comment: hi, I would give you the two select list code below,

<select class="ng-valid ng-dirty" style="" ng-change="selectionsAgentType(AgentType)" ng-model="AgentType">

<select class="ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-change="AgentCategorySelected(agentoptions)" ng-model="agentoptions">

Is there any way could I access this select list?

Comment: @RAJ You can try do it using `xpath` = `b.select_list(:xpath => "(//select)[index]")`  but, I think that `select_lists[index] ` - much better

Comment: hi, I have written this code I hope something similar to what you say here, 

    b.text_field(:index,61).set agentcreation["Referred Name"]

But it's taking too much time to select the item. Time become real concern here for me.

Comment: @RAJ you also can select elements by unique name or id

Comment: Yes I know, I usually to write the code like this, b.select_list(:id,'something').select('hi') but here id is not present and name is not present either instead I found ng-model but I couldn't use that because it throws the error that's because of the '-'.

Comment: @RAJ try write `ng_model`

Comment: Yes, tried, it throws the following error

`rescue in match?': ng_model is an unknown way of finding a <select> element (AgentType) (Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException)

Comment: @RAJ can you add your code with `ng-model` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, I hope you are asking what I have written, here is the code 

b.select_list(:ng_model,'AgentType').select("SP")

Comment: Try this `b.select_list(:xpath =>  './/*[@ng-model="AgentType"]') `

Comment: hey hi, It works, beautiful, but it takes 23 sec to select an element. It takes too much time.

Comment: hi Alex, If I use the code 'b.option(:text,'Agent').select' it selects fine, but the same option Agent is present in two select_list in a single page, So it always selects in the first one, Is there any Can I modify the code to select the second select_list?

Comment: @RAJ If you know an index of the second `select-list` you can write someth like: `b.select_lists[index_of_it].option(:text, 'Agent').select`

Comment: Yes I am aware of this coding, but I can't use index, because any change in the website would affect my coding. For an instance, If they insert a select_list then all index would change. That's what I asked, If same option comes from two different select_list, Can we successfully choose in two select_list?